# Rails: Devise not sending confirmation email in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, production, confirmation

I'm trying to set up email confirmation for new users for my site on Heroku.
It works fine in development (it's sent from the correct email, even though I never specified it in development.rb)

Here is the code in development.rb: (I was using MailCatcher)

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
```

Here is the code in production.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com'}
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :domain => 'myapp.herokuapp.com',  #I've also tried changing this to 'gmail.com'
   :authentication => :plain, # I've also tried changing this to :login
   :enable_starttls_auto => true,
   :user_name => 'mygmailaccount@gmail.com',
   :password => 'mypassword'
 }
```

And here are the last few (of a very long list of) Heroku logs when I type "heroku logs" in the command prompt:

```
2013-11-24T18:51:01.069086+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb
(1.4ms)
2013-11-24T18:50:57.403500+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/
confirmation/new host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=we
b.1 connect=30ms service=18ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-11-24T18:50:32.655624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/users/
sign_up host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=web.1 conne
ct=25ms service=78ms status=304 bytes=0
```

The production site on Heroku just says "We're sorry, but something went wrong." The email never gets sent. The account with the specified email is never logged into the database.

Edit: Here are the log files after I added config.log_level = :debug

```
2013-11-24T20:35:31.602702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=web.1 connect
=2ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-11-24T20:35:13.963743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=web.1 connect
=1ms service=447ms status=200 bytes=0
```

And another one:

```
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-1.4.5/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.694321+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
```

These are only the last few logs. The entire log is too long to copy on here. I'm not sure what to be looking for.

Comment: I've even tried changing the file name development.rb to production.rb and vice-versa to try and see what was going on. In this case, it still worked in development, but not production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup for a Rails app in Heroku that uses Gmail.  Here's the differences...

The `domain` key in you ActionMailer `smtp_settings` shouldn't be necessary as that is only used for Google Apps for Business.  Try removing that config variable and re-deploying your app.

Also, my config doesn't have the following:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

I'd recommend removing those lines as well.

Finally, my `default_url_options` line has a key of `protocol` with a value of `http`.  So, changing that config may help as well:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'http'}
```

Comment: I removed the domain attribute and commented out the three lines and added the http protocol. It's still not working and giving the same error

Comment: The problem is the log file doesn't help much.  Would you increase the log level in production to `DEBUG`, restart your app, and try again?

Comment: I added "config.log_level = :debug" to my production.rb file.

Comment: 2013-11-24T20:35:31.602702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info    method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=web.1 connect
=2ms service=9ms status=304 bytes=0
2013-11-24T20:35:13.963743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favico
n.ico host=myapp.herokuapp.com fwd="118.22.125.86" dyno=web.1 connect
=1ms service=447ms status=200 bytes=0

Comment: I typed heroku logs again and got a different set of logs: 2013-11-24T20:38:32.694321+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rac
k-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2013-11-24T20:38:32.693982+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'

Comment: the above logs are just the end of the logs. I'm not sure what to be looking out for if the key to the error is somewhere in the middle

Comment: Can you add your log files to the question so it's easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

Production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com', :protocol => 'http' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'example@gmail.com',
    password:             'Your gmail password',
    authentication:       'plain'
  }
```

**2nd Step:** 
Go to http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue.

**Reason:** Google was blocking access from unknown location.