# Not receiving email verification link through heroku sendgrid add-on to new sign up gmail account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

In my heroku logs the email confirmation link has been sent successfully but didn't received any mail to gmail account[heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83vKB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some code and/or what you configured would help a lot, just the logs does not really give any clue on what's going on.

Make sure you have configured everything correctly for devise (here are some questions already asked that might help you):

[Rails devise not sending an email confirmation in development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996090/rails-devise-not-sending-an-email-confirmation-in-development)

[Rails: Devise not sending confirmation email in production (Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179740/rails-devise-not-sending-confirmation-email-in-production-heroku)

And I also advise you to not use a gmail account to send emails as they are usually flagged as spam, or sometimes don't even go through at all.

Comment: Thank you man, I was missing smtp as delivery_method in Production.rb. It got resolved now